# Ignoring certain data from the serial port using PySerial and Arduino for ECG

Tags: python, arduino, real-time, pyserial

I am using the PySerial module with the Arduino Uno. I have with the help of fellow stackoverflow users been able to generate a plot of time against ECG value (in volts). However, there is a problem.

When I start the serial port by connecting the Arduino to my computer (via USB) the data starts flowing automatically. Now when I run my Python file it reads the current values coming from the serial port and then restarts to zero again (which I want it to do). I want to ignore, flush or whatever may be appropriate those initial values. You can find the Arduino sketch, Python code and video clip of what is happening below:

Arduino Sketch:

```
#include <eHealth.h>


unsigned long time;
// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

  float ECG = eHealth.getECG();
  time = millis();
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(ECG, 3); 
  Serial.println(""); 


  delay(25);    // wait for 50 millisecond
}
```

Python:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
import matplotlib.figure as mfig
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui, PyQt4.QtCore as core
import collections
import time
import random

import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600)

refreshMillis = 25
N = 200
xs = collections.deque(maxlen=N)
ys = collections.deque(maxlen=N)

app = gui.QApplication([])

fig = mfig.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim([0,5])
line2D, = ax.plot(xs,ys)
canvas.show()

def process_line():
    line = ser.readline()
    data = map(float,line.split(" "))
    xs.append(data[0])
    ys.append(data[1])
    line2D.set_data(xs,ys)
    print data
    xmin, xmax = min(xs),max(xs)
    if xmin == xmax:
        ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmin+1])
    else:
        ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
    canvas.draw()

timer = core.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(process_line)
timer.start(refreshMillis)

app.exec_()

ser.flush()
ser.close()
```

Video clip:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNpUakcRPec

As you can when I run the python file shown above, the first few values which are time in the left column and voltage value on the right column are the current values from the port, they then reset and this can be seen on the plot which causes this initial mess which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Dump all input, byte-by-byte, until you get a newline?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would I do that, I have tried flushInput() but that didn't appear to work or at least not how I intended.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just send a "start signal" from the python script to the arduino telling it to start sending ?

In the `void setup()` add a while loop that runs till you recieve "Start" from the pc then start sending.